# I need to create a table in MYSQL from MSSQL and insert/update data

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I have a MS SQL 2008 server with a database and need to create a table in MYSQL from a table/data in  MS SQL. The mysql database has been linked and I have full access to the database. Can I do this using openquery?

Answer (score 0):

`OPENQUERY` doesn't let you run DDL statements against remote databases.  To the best of my knowledge, MySQL doesn't have an equivalent method of interacting with other RDBMS's.

You can however do this from SQL Server using the Import/Export Wizard to copy your table to MySQL.  You may need to install [MyOleDB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/myoledb/) or a similar driver to connect to MySQL.

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052%28v=sql.105%29.aspx